# MS SQL Вывести список старших в комнате, где живут дети

Tags: sql, sql-server

В базе данных в MS SQL заданы таблицы жильцы, комнаты, этаж.
В таблице "Жильцы" присутствует по несколько человек в комнате, некоторым есть 18, а некоторым нет (это и есть дети), вот в этих комнатах, где присутствует хоть один ребёнок - нужно вывести ФИО и дату рождения (или возраст) самого старшего в комнате.
Скрины таблиц и запрос, который пытался сделать прилагаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT ID_Жильца, фио_жильца
FROM Жильцы
WHERE
```

Не совсем понимаю, что нужно вписать в последней строчке после WHERE

Comment: Со скринами - это на фотовыставку. А здесь - только форматированный текст. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: Сначала хотя бы получи список комнат, где есть дети.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что последняя строчка совсем не последняя